# How to set the pointer to the current row in the Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview on the Windows Form in c#. I am updating and filling  the table adapter on the cell event. The problem is that When I go to lower half of the datagrid which is not visible until I scroll down, as I click any cell, the table adapter is filled and updated and the pointerpoints to the very first row.
Any suggestion on how to fix it. I have a ideas to record the top row of the datagridview that is visible and set the pointer to that row. But how to  do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92008/programmatically-setting-the-record-pointer-in-a-c-sharp-datagridview Here zou have the answer